# C# Сканирование порта на наличие IP адресов

Tags: c#, .net, сеть, tcp, сканирование-портов

Собственно, задачка: есть четко известный порт. Пусть, к примеру 10001. Я создаю на нем TcpListener, стартую его на порту 10001 и, если ввести IP адрес машины всё коннектится и чудно работает, но! Как создать теперь сканер, который просканирует весь порт и покажет всех, кто есть на этом порту, что бы уже потом дать пользователю выбрать и после присоединится к одному из них? Как вывести всё на экран я и так знаю, мне непонятно, как получить этот масив IP адресов. Перебором по диапазону от 0.0.0.0 до 255.255.255.255?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

два момента:

1. IP-адрес определяет конкретный компьютер, порт определяет конкретный сервис данного компьютера. Именно в таком порядке, поэтому никакого списка IP-адресов для порта быть не может в принципе, но может быть список разрешенных портов для IP-адреса.
2. Да, действовать придется перебором по диапазону. Для глобальных сетей это единственный вариант. В локальной сети можно повесить `UdpListener` на соседний порт у клиентов и сделать BroadCast запрос на этот порт, тем самым сообщив всем о своем присутствии в сети и готовности принимать подключения. После чего, все получившие этот запрос и желающие подключиться, знают к кому подключаться и могут это сделать. Можно сделать наоборот, и в ответ на udp broadcast отправлять свою готовность принимать подключения, тогда собрав все ответы можно будет выбрать к кому подключаться. НО еще раз напоминаю, broadcast запросы допустимы только внутри локальной сети, в глобальных сетях они, как правило, режутся.

Comment: Окей. Если так оно не работает... Тогда как узнать свой IP в локальной сети?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx#Anchor_6 посмотрите этот пример на MSDN, там показано как получить всю информацию о всех сетевых интерфейсах

Answer (score 0):

"Задачка" чисто архитектурного характера. Для ее решения вам надо:

- При каждом ESTABLISHED соединении заносить конкретный IP этого соединения в некий список - запоминать на стороне сервера(листенера)
- Для получения списка "подключенных" IP(ESTABLISHED state) можно посылать какой-нибудь ключ(псевдозапрос) или открыть еще один порт чисто для выдачи всех установленных соединений

P.S И первый пункт можно отбросить, насколько помню, - компонент TcpListener и так знает обо всех активных подключениях.